# IndexError: list index out of range, django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to access the data from the social account. And for that I am following [this](http://piratelearner.com/en/C/course/computer-science/django/django-all-auth-all-you-need-to-know/8/) site.

**What is the problem?**

I am getting the following error after successfully logged in to my facebook account:

***Error***: `IndexError at /accounts/facebook/login/callback/`

`list index out of range`

Looking it up on the internet I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084721/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-django-allauth-signals) post and tried to implement it but that gave a `keyerror 'user'`.

**My Code:**

***adaptar.py*:**

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

class CustomAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

   def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
      account_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, provider='facebook')
      print account_uid[0].extra_data['first_name']
```

***settings.py:***

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'Authentication.adapter.CustomAdapter'
```

Comment: Well, presumably your query on SocialAccount is returning an empty list. What makes you think the record should exist?

Comment: I just did this `print account_uid` and it prints this `<QuerySet []>` on the console. which means you were right it does return empty string. but how can i fix this ? please help. :(

Comment: `request.user.id` returns `None`.

Comment: better u can write a proper code for facebook and google

Comment: @Gowthaman What is wrong with my code ? can you please elaborate ? and i don't use google as a social app but code for that would be pretty similar.

Comment: @Gowthaman I like to know people's suggestions. I respect them i really do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found the solution:**

Instead of using `SocialAccount` model to get the user data I used the passed parameter `sociallogin` to get the user data like following:

**solution:**

***adaptar.py:***

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class CustomAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):   
      def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
         if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
            first_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['first_name'] 
            print first_name
```

**changed this:**

```
 account_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, provider='facebook')
```

**to this:**

```
if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
   first_name = sociallogin.account.extra_data['first_name']
```